# Input field in a HTML table pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML table with 4 rows. 3 are already filled rows and I want the user to fill the last rows that later will be retrieved to perform a calculation. Is there a way to do this in plain javascript (no jquery).

This is the code of my table

```
<table id = "user_feature">
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Comedy</th>
    <th>Horror</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>0.3</td>
    <td>0.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jonny</td>
    <td>0.7</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kimi</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
    <td>0.9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>You</td>
    <td input text="placeholder" name="comedy" id="comedy">edit</td>
    <td input text="placeholder" name="horror" id="horror">edit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here the complete playground that I am using to understand how HTML and Javascript work  together to create tables https://jsfiddle.net/sj36zq12/1/

Comment: Did you try using `<input>`?

Comment: Looks like you did some odd combination of <td> and <input> into 1 tag.

Comment: why do you think td elements use input attributes?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I have not nested the <input> tag inside the <td> one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nest the `<input>` elements inside the `<td>` elements. No JavaScript is needed, this is just plain HTML.

```html
<table id="user_feature">
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Comedy</th>
    <th>Horror</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>0.3</td>
    <td>0.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jonny</td>
    <td>0.7</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kimi</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
    <td>0.9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>You</td>
    <td><input text="placeholder" name="comedy" id="comedy">edit</td>
    <td><input text="placeholder" name="horror" id="horror">edit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that I could nest the input in the table row! And how can I save the result as a number and not as a string? Because at the moment, I have the input filled but I cannot perform my calculation since is a string

Comment: The same way as if it weren't in the table. Call `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on the input value.